# Работа с изображениями на Android

Tags: java, android, изображения

Приветствую. Для проекта требуется работать с изображениями, а именно: взять изображение из drawable, по заданным координатам вставить картинки и текст, сохранить. Подскажите как это можно реализовать, есть какие-либо библиотеки? Буду благодарен.

Comment: Как вариант, на Canvas рисуете, то что вам нужно. После можно вытащить Bitamp из Canvas и сохранить его.

Comment: Спасибо. Странно, на английской версии stackoverflow подобный мой мой пост заминусовали и удалили. Может не так поняли...